# Windows IP conflict after setting Static IP

Tags: dns, ip, gateway, ipv4

I am having troubles setting my static IP address.

I double check all of my default settings and tried to make my IP static. Here is what I entered

[image]

I have tried various different IP addres 192.168.1.1(05, 34, 35, 67, 99).

Each time I am told there has been an IP conflict.

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: It (usually) means there is another machine on the network with the IP address you are trying to set.  ARE there other machines on the network? What's the ACTUAL error message you get?

Comment: I wouldn't expect all of them to be taken, though. Is this a home network? Do you have access to the router settings?

Comment: What were the settings it had previously when it was set to Auto Obtain?

Comment: I had my router reserving the IP 192.168.1.100 - 199. I just changed the ranged and set my static ip to 160

Comment: If you are setting a static IP on a computer, it should be outside the IP range reserved for DHCP. That alone won't solve conflicts, but helps. What does the router show for current connections? Can you set the router to do a static DHCP lease instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say you "had your router reserving the IP 192.168.1.100-199".  Usually, routers are by default configured to *serve* these IP addresses in their DHCP pool.  *Reservations* are typically used when you have specific systems that you want to always receive the same IP.

If you want to be able to arbitrarily set your system to a static IP, make sure it is outside of your router's DHCP pool.  Alternatively, you could set your router so that the IP address you want is *reserved* to your system and then set your system to use DHCP.